# which one is suitable ? I want to say that Jane is a good friend of mine and I know her very well

Tags: tenses

Jane is a good friend of mine. I know / have known her very well.

1) know 
2) have known

Which one is suitable? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"1) know"  would be the appropriate option. 
"2) have known" would be incorrect grammatically.

Comment: You would use "have known" only in reference to _how long_ (time) you knew her.  "I have known her {three years/since she was a child/all my life/etc}."

Comment: This is the correct answer, Rahul, but to a question not suitable for ELU. And even correct answers are usually required to be backed by supporting evidence (eg from a grammar).